# adding new users to the database upon registering on a website using JSP and JDBC

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am now working on a web application project for the first time, the application includes registering and adding users to the database, now i wrote a java class called DatabaseManager that implements all database operations, and wrote the JSP page responsible for adding new users, if the registration is successful I need to add the user's details to the database, so I was wondering, do I need to create a instance of DatabaseManager and load the database driver and initialise the connection everytime a new user registers or is there a more efficient way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the database driver can be done just only once during webapp's startup. You can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) for this. You could do the driver loading task in the constructor of the `DatabaseManager` class and instantiate it during [`contextInitialized()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) and store the instance in the application scope so that it is available to all servlets in the context (noted should be that JSP is in essence the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) place for business logic).

Opening (and closing!) the `Connection` should really be done directly in the very same method block as you're executing the SQL query. It should certainly not be "cached" as a static/instance variable somewhere in your application logic. To improve connecting performance, the normal practice is to configure a connection pool to obtain the connections from. In every decent servletcontainer you can do this in flavor of a JNDI datasource.

Long story short, you can find a JSP/Servlet example utilizing the above techniques in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html) which is by coincidence also using an use case of "register user".

Comment: thanks BalusC, having followed your tutorial and your explanation here helped me connect all the stuff that I read about servlets.